# Trouble with .Net ASP.Net MVC project and dotnet.yml build

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, github-actions, .net-sdk

We're new to GitHub. We've committed our project and were trying create a build.
We started using the default dotnet.yml.
Our version of Visual Studio is 2017 and we tried using .Net 4.5.2 and then upgraded to 4.6.2 trying that as well.
We were getting an error, as it seemed to be using .Net Core, so we changed the following
runs-on: ubuntu-latest ==> runs-on: windows-2019
After that we're getting the following error (among others)
The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.416\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found.
We tried to add the NuGet packages in Visual Studio

MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets
MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web_WebApplication.Targets
But then get this error:
Unable to resolve dependencies. 'Microsoft.Net.Compilers 1.3.2' is not compatible with 'Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform 1.0.8 constraint: Microsoft.Net.Compilers (>= 2.4.0)'.
What can we need to upgrade here and with what repurcusions?

Comment: You are using the .NET Core specific template, and that's why it failed. You need to switch to a .NET Framework specific template, or simply use the search engines to find a working example.